# Why does my android border not display?

Tags: android

border.xml:

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >    
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <stroke
            android:width="1dip"
            android:color="#cbcbcb" />    
        <corners android:radius="7dp" />    
    </shape>
```

Set Background of LinearLayout:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
       //Child control
    </LinearLayout>
```

If  LinearLayout has some child control: border display ok. But If LinearLayout  have very  much child controls, border can't display. 
Why border not display? how set border in this case?

Comment: Give the `layout_height` it will display the border.In this `wrap_content` represents `0dp`.

Comment: If LinearLayout has some child control: bolder display ok. But If LinearLayout have very much child controls, bolder can't display

Comment: if the child have height,it will show the border.if child also have wrap_content means it will not show the border.Just give the padding for Linear layout it show the border in wrap_content.

Comment: Try to change android:width="1dip" to android:width="1dp".

Comment: number my child controls is auto. if set value of Height, when add child controls to LinearLayout, It will can't display

Answer (score 0):

because of this line :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

when the LinearLayout doesn't have a child so wrap_content in `android:layout_height` cause that LinearLayout height to 0dp and nothing gonna show.set some size to your Layout and border will show up.

Comment: If LinearLayout has some child control: bolder display ok. But If LinearLayout have very much child controls, bolder can't display

Comment: @DT : because of wrap_content if you have childerns Views which their View sizes go outside of your physycal screen width also your LinearLayout border would not be shown.

Comment: number my child controls is auto. so i have to set layout_height="wrap_content".